# What do the numbers indicate which are displayed on the left side of the profile image?

Tags: support

If we click on [Top Users](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/magento/topusers) in any tag, we can see as in the below image.

Here I didn't understand 11, 4, 5K, and 800 which is displayed on the left side of the profile image.

[image]

Comment: The numbers are total score and number of answers

Comment: If you mouseover the numbers you'll get a short description.